# Add row according to a existence Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that contains:

```
ID_POINT ID_PRODUCT QUANTITY
A        11          5
A        52          10
B        30          20
C        11          2
```

and i have averall product id's

```
ID_PRODUCT
11
20
30
44
52
```

With this two table i want to create this table :

```
ID_POINT ID_PRODUCT QUANTITY
A        11          5
A        52          10
A        20          0
A        30          0
A        44          0
B        30          20
B        11          0
B        20          0
B        30          0
B        44          0
B        52          0
C        11          2
C        20          0
C        30          0
C        44          0
C        52          0
```

So if first dataset ant id point doesnt contains any id_product it must be added on the dataset with 0 quantity.

```
data = pd.read_csv('first.csv', delimiter=",")  # reading the file. 
products = pd.read_csv('products.csv', delimiter=",")  # reading the file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If many groups and performance is important better is same order of `ID_PRODUCT` for each group - use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['ID_POINT'].unique(), df2['ID_PRODUCT']],
                                  names=['ID_POINT','ID_PRODUCT'])
df = df1.set_index(['ID_POINT','ID_PRODUCT']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
   ID_POINT  ID_PRODUCT  QUANTITY
5         A          11         5
6         A          20         0
7         A          30         0
8         A          44         0
9         A          52        10
10        B          11         0
11        B          20         0
12        B          30        20
13        B          44         0
14        B          52         0
15        C          11         2
16        C          20         0
17        C          30         0
18        C          44         0
19        C          52         0
```

Or create `DataFrame` with all possible combinations and use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
from  itertools import product

df3 = pd.DataFrame(product(df1['ID_POINT'].unique(),  df2['ID_PRODUCT']),
                   columns=['ID_POINT','ID_PRODUCT'])
df = df3.merge(df1, how='left').fillna({'QUANTITY': 0})
print (df)
   ID_POINT  ID_PRODUCT  QUANTITY
0         A          11       5.0
1         A          20       0.0
2         A          30       0.0
3         A          44       0.0
4         A          52      10.0
5         B          11       0.0
6         B          20       0.0
7         B          30      20.0
8         B          44       0.0
9         B          52       0.0
10        C          11       2.0
11        C          20       0.0
12        C          30       0.0
13        C          44       0.0
14        C          52       0.0
```

Comment: Using multiindex is a nice idea here, more elegant than mine :-)

Comment: @yatu - yes, another problem should be performance with `apply + merge`...

Comment: Yes, I'll rmeove it that's another issue @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by one line code (assuming you meant join/merge by add)

```
products.set_index("ID_PRODUCT").join(data[data["QUANTITY"] != 0].set_index("ID_PRODUCT"), how = "left")
```

Answer (score -1):

what you need my friend is called 'outer join'. what can be achieved in pandas like so.

```
     new_merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID_PRODUCT', how='outer')
     new_merged_df.fillna(0,inplace = True)
```

hope that helps

Comment: It says : merge() got multiple values for argument 'how'

Comment: i cant seem to reproduce that error. kindly upload the rest of code

Answer (score -1):

you can merge two dataframes

```
output = pd.merge(products,data,how="left",on=["ID_PRODUCT"]).fillna(0)
```